# Redux-React Programming Practices

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to understand the best practices when writing and achieving the best abstraction. Should all functions be action creators when writing redux-react applications, or should functions where it is not necessary to edit the store go directly into components and be called from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action creators are for managing state. They are a very specific type of function that generate actions that are processed by your reducer. There are a lot of other computations and things you can do in your app besides manage state, and for those things you should not use action creators. You don’t necessarily have to put the functions in your components. You can also put them in a helper folder, for example, and then import them.